# Rgraph show key when cliking line

Tags: tooltip, rgraph

I want to display a tooltip when I click a line graph, along with the usual tooltip with the value.
Is there any way to link from the canvas to the key area?!

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the interactive key?

http://www.rgraph.net/docs/interactive-keys.html

It's not a tooltip though - it highlights an entry on the key.

**EDIT:**

There's an example of a poly object that has been positioned to sit over the line(s) and which when clicked highlights the appropriate key entry. It wasn't simple to accomplish (lots of playing with coordinates) - but neither was it like trying to remember your wifes birthday when drunk:

http://www.rgraph.net/tests/spline-key-clickable.html

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I'm referring the interactive key. I want to click the line  inside the graph and the key became highlighted. The implementation from rgraph does it, but in the reverse from what I need.

Comment: There's nothing automatic - but using the obj.coords variable you could draw a poly (using the drawing API poly object) around the line and then, when clicked, call the obj.interactiveKeyHighlight(index) function that will highlight the appropriate key entry. You can avoid using the Poly object if you were happy to click the Line chart points - in that case you could use the onclick event: obj.onclick (in all cases obj reffers to your RGraph line chart object). I'd recommend doing that first even if you do then start using the Poly object.

Comment: Can you please send me an example? I'm not at all an expert in javascript

Comment: I don't have an example of that I'm afraid. If you're not good at JavaScript you should keep in mind that it might get 'involved'.

Comment: I'll make one up for you and let you know the link (tomorrow at the earliest now)

Comment: I know that I need to Javascript. I'm starting with it

Comment: Ok sorry - it'll be Monday before I can get the example to you.

Comment: Ok the answer has been updated with the URL of an example. Click the line and the key will be highlighted as well as the tooltip being shown.

Comment: Thanks @Richard It works fine, I changed the coordsspline for coords2 and it works also with a non curvy line graph

Comment: Any idea how to make this code work with trace2() instead of draw()?

Comment: Ah I was doing the same but getting obj.drawPoly is not a function. The problem seems to be that keyInteractive was set as true. I guess we can't have both the bits.